# Dynamic Grid ANGULAR with BARCODE generator

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, barcode

I am studying Angular.
I am making an application: an user choose from one html selection, then fill two input fields. After this, the user press Update and the barcode script generates the code image with 3 parameters: the first select and the two input. ( these three are separated by some spaces ). So far, no problem.

I've added the button for add new forms, and the json array save the input correctly. I wanted to generate a barcode for each compiled form. How can i do?
This is an easy example of what i am doing:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/hxZb6g9tkwN0zpRmOMjw?p=preview
```

at the end of html you can find the script of barcode:

```
<div class="ean">
        <img id="barcodeImage" style="border: solid 1px black;"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updateBarcode() 
        {
                var barcode = new bytescoutbarcode128();
                var space= "  ";
            var value = document.getElementById("barcodeValue").value;
            var value1 = document.getElementById("barcodeValue1").value;
            var value2 = document.getElementById("barcodeValue2").value;

            barcode.valueSet(value + space + value1 + space + value2);
            barcode.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
            barcode.setBarWidth(2);

            var width = barcode.getMinWidth();

            barcode.setSize(width, 100);

            var barcodeImage = document.getElementById('barcodeImage');
            barcodeImage.src = barcode.exportToBase64(width, 100, 0);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) (also take a look here - http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html, http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs) to generate barcode and also put this directive in ng-repeat loop in your template:

```
app.directive('barcode', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: '<img id="barcodeImage" style="border: solid 1px black;" src="{{src}}"/>',
    scope: {
      food: '='
    },
    link: function($scope){
      $scope.$watch('food', function(food){
        console.log($scope.food);
        var barcode = new bytescoutbarcode128();
        var space= "  ";

            barcode.valueSet([$scope.food.selectproduct, $scope.food.Quantity1, $scope.food.Quantity2].join(space));
            barcode.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
            barcode.setBarWidth(2);

            var width = barcode.getMinWidth();

            barcode.setSize(width, 100);

            $scope.src = barcode.exportToBase64(width, 100, 0);
      }, true);
    }
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/z2nXgXyGi6LhSHth8ZNi?p=preview